# How to kill (healers) with Subtlety Rogue

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I currently have a Gnome Subtlety Rogue lvl 55. I am building her specifically for PVP.
Currently my biggest problem is trying to kill healers 1v1. These can be priests or warlocks or paladins,
with ambush I'm able to knock them down to about 1/10 health, but before I normally can finish them off
they're able to do a full heal, and of course then going 1v1 against them I normally lose as they keep
healing and I'm unable too.

Lvl right now is 55 but I'm going till 85, but do enjoy doing pvp along the way.

Are there any specific tactics for dealing with healers?

Assuming I'm 1v1 against a random healer in a battleground, and no one else interferes.

Comment: Healing is vastly overpowered during the new leveling phase, as the magnitude of the spells available often eclipses the total health pool of its caster.

Comment: Though warlocks have some abilities that provide some self-healing, they are considered a pure damage-dealing class, not a healer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stun. Lock. I'm a hardcore pvp healer, and that's pretty much it for me. Backstab, kick, stun, dead. You can always vanish, if at first you don't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Use Stun lock. Don't forget that you may use explosive to stun lock. And don't forget anti magic-user poisons.

Comment: Which poisons are anti magic-users? Are these sold in the old city in SW? Hmm I'll check when I get home.

Comment: Mind-Numbing and Wound Poison are what I assume he's referring to. They should be available at your level.

Comment: Yes exactly. Mind-Numbling reduce casting time speed by 30% and Wound Poison reduce healing effect by 10%.